# ¿Como insertar un valor de un array dependiendo del ID en un input?

Tags: php, html

tengo el siguiente codigo en PHP y HTML:

En el form donde recibo los datos:

```
 <form autocomplete="off" action="insertar.php" method="post">
    foreach($data["bajos"] as $dato){
        $cal_id = $dato["cal_id"];
        $pco_nombre = $dato["pco_nombre"];
        $pas_nombre = $dato["pas_nombre"];
        ?> <p class="card-text"><strong><?php echo $pco_nombre; ?></strong></p>
        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $pas_nombre; ?></p>
        <p class="card-text">
        <div style="float:right;">
        <label>Votacion:</label>
        <input type="number" name="cal_id" id="<?php echo $cal_id;?>" value="<?php echo $cal_id;?>">
        <input type="number" name="votacion[]" id="votacion"></input>
        </div> <?php
        }
        ?>
        <button type="submit" id="submit3" name="boton1" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Guardar" type="button">Consultar</button>
        </form>
```

Y se ve asi dentro de la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el codigo que anexé anteriormente hay 2 input number, dentro de los cuales 1 ya esta alimentado con un ID.

El código del action es este:

```
if(isset($_POST['votacion'])){
                $votos = $_POST['votacion']; //Se reciben los datos de el input donde digita el usuario
            }
            
            if(isset($_POST['cal_id'])){
                $cal_id = $_POST['cal_id']; //Se reciben los datos que ya estaban alimentados anteriormente para el QUERY
            }

            sort($votos); //Organizo de menor a mayor el array de Votos
            $voto = max($votos); //Tomo el valor del array mayor para insertarlo en el QUERY

            echo "Se insertara el valor: ".$voto." y su ID es: ".$cal_id."";
```

Pero a la hora de ver el resultado arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y con cualquier numero que ponga siempre es el mismo ID

¿Hay algo que este haciendo mal? Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el lado servidor, como ya sabes la información de un formulario enviado con POST es recibida en el array-diccionario $_POST. Las claves de este array son los **atributos name** de cada campo del formulario. Si te fijas, en tu bucle generas varios inputs, pero todos tienen el mismo name="cal_id", por tanto finalmente el formulario solo envía un único valor, normalmente el último (en algunos navegadores podría ser el primero).

### Actualizo

Tendrás que darle un name distinto a cada input o bien `name = "cal_id[]"`. Al tener [] en el nombre, todos los valores de los campos se enviarán en un array. Entonces $cal_id será un array con todos los valores. Así, $cal_id[0] te daría el valor del primer input (en tu imagen creo que es 203, salvo que haya alguno más arriba).

Por cierto, si ya usas max no necesitas ordenar el array de votaciones. Y de forma contraria, si ordenas, no necesitas max (el mayor estará en última posición, si ordenas de menor a mayor).

Si en lugar de usar max o sort recorres con un for clásico buscando el máximo, te será fácil identificar el índice de donde se encuentra. De este modo puedes usar el mismo índice en $cal_id para obtener la id correspondiente.

Código:

```php
// Lo que ya tenías:
if(isset($_POST['votacion'])){
    // Referencias al array de votos en una variable $votos
    $votos = $_POST['votacion'];
}
            
if(isset($_POST['cal_id'])){
    // Referencias al array de ids en una variable $cal_id
    $cal_id = $_POST['cal_id'];
}
// -----------------------------------

// Lo nuevo:

// Esto nos da la posición del mayor de los votos.
$indice_del_mayor = array_keys($votos, max($votos))[0];

// Usamos dicha posición para obtener del array cal_id la id
$id_del_mayor = $cal_id[$indice_del_mayor];

// Usamos también dicha posición para obtener el valor en sí.
$voto_del_mayor = $votos[$indice_del_mayor];

echo "Se insertara el valor: " . $voto_del_mayor. " y su ID es: " . $id_del_mayor;
```

### Cómo funciona

array_keys te devuelve las claves del array (en un array convencional, su índice), pero también admite un elemento de búsqueda. Si le damos el mayor de los valores, nos dará todas las posiciones que contengan dicho valor. Como solo nos interesa una, obtenemos la primera de ellas, por si hay repetidos con [0].

Una vez se tiene la posición (índice) del mayor, podemos usarla en ambos arrays para obtener el valor (el voto) y su id.

Comment: Hola, la verdad si me gustaría que me ayudases en este tema, soy nuevo y realmente quisiera aprender sobre este tipo de problemáticas, agradezco tu colaboración!

Comment: @Decox he actualizado la respuesta. Ya tenías algo similar con los datos de los input con name votacion. Añades [] para enviar un array con todas las IDs de los inputs con name cal_id. Evidentemente ahora tendrás que buscar el índice de donde estaba el mayor para usarlo en el array de las IDs. Con un for manual para buscar el mayor en lugar de usar max o sort, es sencillo.

Comment: @Decox te dejo una respuesta mejor sin for. He vuelto a actualizar. Un saludo.

Comment: Te agradezco un montón por compartir tu conocimiento, en serio, es de apreciar un montón y realmente es de agradecer; Lo he entendido todo perfectamente, pero a la hora de insertar el codigo con la sintaxis que me diste en la respuesta aparece el siguiente error: Warning: Use of undefined constant indice_del_mayor - assumed 'indice_del_mayor' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) ¿Sabes que podria ser ello? Nuevamente, gracias! Edicion: Lo solucioné agregando simplemente el "$" para indicar la variable, nuevamente muchas gracias y que Dios bendiga tu conocimiento y a los tuyos!

Comment: @Decox sí, perdón, me olvidé del signo del dolar delante de las variables, maldito php. Hace años que no trabajo con él. Ya está corregido.